# Hide 'On my iPhone' calendar when syncing with MobileMe

Tags: mobileme, calendar

Ive now switched back over to MobileMe for all of my calendar stuff.

I was wondering though, if I go to 'Calendars', it also displays a calendar 'On My iPhone'. I don't think I would ever want to use it (because I want it to write to one of my two MobileMe Calendars).

Is there any way to remove this other calendar? Or at least make it so its not the 'default' one? Even if I tell the iPhone to not show it - it still wants to write to that calendar by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly - the only way to remove it is convoluted. Get a backup and make sure you understand the steps.

First temporarily remove all sync accounts (deleting the data from the phone - it's only on the cloud and on the backup now) and then sync with the USB with a checkmark to overwrite the calendar data on the phone one time. Then disable USB calendar syncing and the phone (or iTunes) will prompt and offer to let you delete the calendar at long last.

Only then can you add back the calendars you want from the cloud.

In the mean time, you can go to the settings app, and at the bottom of "Mail, Contacts, Calendars" is a place to set the default calendar for new events.

Comment: I think this is the only way to do it. I got a new phone (refurb), and set it up fresh, and this calendar wasn't there. But this is the only answer that really tries to answer the question. Basically its just deleting the calendars and resetting its state and pulling the ones I actually want back down from MobileMe

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you can change this settings in iCal, as your mobile me settings are in there.  I did this, and my iPhone only shows my Mobile me calendars.

If you use gmail, I would also reccomend [BusySync](http://www.busymac.com/busysync/index.html). It syncs anything you add to you iCal, and then iCal and mobile me syncs.  Its pure awesomeness in my opinion.

Also, if you have devleoper tools enabled, you can edit the plist mobileme sync-time interval to 1 min, instead of 15.  You can access the mobile me plist file in home/library/preferences/byhost/ - the specific file name is like: com.apple.mobilemesync.. or something like that.  Im at work, and use a linux system, so if someone else knows, please confirm, otherwise i will update this when i get home.

Comment: iCal on the phone, or Mac? Also no, moving from Google Calendar, and don't need any other app. And yes, I have developer tools installed, but don't have a problem with the current sync times - and you can do it manually any time you want.

Comment: iCal on the mac, sorry.  Reason I said busy sync, is because when im at work I can add an event to google cal, and within 5 mins, its on my iphone. Same in the opposite direction.. if im on the go, and add a event to my iphone, its on my google calendar within mins.  The default sync times are not "push" so changing it to 1 min interval, makes it feel like it is "push"

Comment: yah, googles built in sync relying on exchange somewhat worked for me, but was messing up my contacts too much. So with that and better calendars through MobileMe, I switched back.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this, but --

On the iPhone Under Settings then "Mail, Contacts, Calendars" then the Calendars section there is a preference to set the default calendar for new events created on the iPhone.

I'd assume you could change the default to an existing calendar, move any "On My iPhone" events to another calendar, make sure the changes have synced, and then delete the "On My iPhone" calendar in iCal.

Comment: how does one delete the On My iPhone calendar in iCal on the phone? I couldn't seem to find this.

Comment: Select the calendar then on the menu bar "Edit" and then "Delete." Sorry, I thought it also accepted the big delete key, but it doesn't.

Comment: changing the default works. But still don' think you can delete this calendar from the iPhone. And it doesn't sync back to my iMacs copy of iCal

Comment: yes you can.  I have only Mobile me calendars showing.  If I had my mac, i would show you step by step directions on how to change this..

Comment: Could you let me know when you check this out? I still can't find how to remove them on the phone. And haven't seen how they even show up on the computer.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but if the "On My iPhone" calendar isn't getting sent to iCal, I'd check your sync settings in iTunes (while the phone is connected) to make sure all your calendars are getting synced. Something to try, anyway.